# kde panel blinks all the time when I move mouse over it fast in kubuntu 20.04

Tags: intel-graphics, intel, panel, plasma-5, kde5

When I move my mouse fast it causes the panel to blink (rapidly disappears and appears).

When I move the mouse slowly over panel it does not blink.

Probably this is related to render of window contents.

i915 is in use and GLX is enabled.

```
slava@slava-Aspire-5742G:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core 
Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Core Processor 
Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915


slava@slava-Aspire-5742G:~$ glxinfo | grep Device
    Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics (ILK) (0x46)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Do you know for sure you are using the right video driver?

Comment: How to check this?